# Finding the Antiderivative of $x^{-2}(1+x^{-1})^x$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm currently working on solving the following limit/integral:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t{\frac 1{x^2}\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^{-x}dx}$$

Here's what I've established so far:

1. The integral converges.

   -*Easily proven by direct comparison test with $\frac1{x^2}$*
2. A u-sub isn't exactly the most helpful.

   -*Leads to $\int_\infty^1 u^{-\frac1{u-1}}du$, which I also can't figure out.*
3. The problem is hard.

I've also tried differentiation under the integral sign with $f(x,t) = \frac t{x^2}\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^{-x}$ and $t=-1$, but that was also unhelpful.

If anyone can show that the integral actually *doesn't* converge, or at least provide guidance in where to go, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: I probably wouldn't write it this way because that would hamper your problem solving ability. Use $t$ for the limit variable and the upper bound. As written the integral actually *diverges* because near $0$ we have $$x^{-2}\left(1+x^{-1}\right)^{-x} \sim x^{-2}$$ The ambiguity of which is supposed to be the limit variable and which is supposed to be the integration variable extends to the integrand, as the integral would converge if the leading term were $t^{-2}$ instead of $x$.